# Set of confidence intervals for linear combinations of linear regression coefficients

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model

If $$ y_i = b_0 + b_1 x_i + e_i $$ are linear regressions with $ e_i $  independent and identically distributed $N(0,v^2)$, how do I obtain a set of confidence intervals $ a_0 b_0 + a_1 b_1 $ such that the overall confidence level for the whole set is $( (1-a)\times100) \%$ ?

Comment: Are $a_0$ and $a_1$ some constants?

Comment: They are constants, but not fixed. How does one obtain a set of confidence intervals over all linear combinations?

Comment: Use the formula for [variance of a sum of two random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) to get the standard error of the sum. The CI is the sum $\pm$ critical value times the standard error.

Comment: But how does the fact that the overall confidence level for the whole set should be (1-a)*100% factor in?

Comment: The only reason I can see to do this is if you're using your CIs like hypothesis tests and you want to control for multiple comparisons at the alpha level. If that's your reason then don't. The CIs are not hypothesis tests, they are estimates of a range of plausible values. That estimate is unaffected by other estimates you calculate regardless of whether alpha or beta rates are.

Either use tests and correct or use estimates that locate the population values. Don't conflate the two just because they can have some similar inferential properties..

Comment: The critical values depend on the $a$. For instance, 5% will correspond to 1.96.